# Bluetooth keyboard with Android?

Tags: bluetooth, external-keyboard

Can I use a bluetooth keyboard with Android?

Comment: This question needs new answers, the most recent one is from 2011.

Answer (score 7):

Android natively doesn't support the Bluetooth HID profile which would be required for this. So, your options are limited depending on whether you're rooted or not:

1. (If rooted): [This YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajmhUcmbinc&feature=related) shows the Nexus One connected to a Microsoft Wireless Entertainment Keyboard 7000.
2. (If not rooted): [Teksoft](http://www.teksoftco.com/index.php?section=blueinputandroid) provide a Bluetooth HID driver (commercially, costs about 10 Euros), which is reportedly successful.

Note: Individual devices that run Android may have the HID profile added by their manufacturer -- for example, the Dell Streak supports Bluetooth keyboards.

Comment: When this answer was written, Android Froyo (2.2) was the most recent Android version. Maybe things have changed?

Answer (score 3):

Android 3.0+ supports several bluetooth keyboards such as the [Logitech Tablet Keyboard](http://www.logitech.com/keyboards/keyboard/devices/8232), which I use successfully with my Android 4.0 phone (not tablet) for note-taking and IM.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It does now. I am using an iTrivia Palmkey on my Galaxy S2 running Gingerbread 2.3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just pair with the keyboard and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I paired with my folding EC Technology Bluetooth [keyboard](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00QT8WQ86) on the first attempt. Alas I find that one or two very useful characters by default require awkward multi-key presses (see [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/111740/reconfiguring-a-bluetooth-keyboard-on-android)).