# How to type SMS in a full sized keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, sms, usb

The only way I have to send SMS is through my Android Phone, since I don't have a GSM/3G modem.

I would like to use my Desktop's keyboard to type those SMSes.

Is there any application that would allow me to type in the keyboard and the keystrokes echo in the Android device, through bluetooth or an USB cable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [WiFi Keyboard](http://androidedge.com/wifi-keyboard-android-app-remote-keyboard-pc-435) -- allows you to use your desktop's keyboard to control the Android.

NB: I have not personally tried this, but it looks pretty cool. aimed particularly at apps that require keyboard input, but still don't pop-up a virtual keyboard......

Again, WiFi, not BlueTooth. aaargh. Unless, you know, you get your PC to broadcast on BlueTooth.

Answer (score 4):

bear in mind; solution preseted next is very geek centric....

Root the phone; install [vnc server](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/communication/droid-vnc-server_iwam.html) on phone and vnc client on computer.
Connect either by usb or wifi ; and use remote desktop to send sms.
:D

p.s. yes, i know you probably wanted some sort of [bluetooth usb](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/525/bluetooth-keyboard-with-android)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a Google Voice account, you could also head to http://voice.google.com/ and type your SMS messages there. Of course, have the Google Voice app on your phone so that you can sync your messages with your desktop. It works really well.

Comment: I lurve Google Voice.

Comment: If only it was available outside the US :(

Comment: @GAThrawn - Yeah. They're apparently working on it now. Hopefully you guys get it soon!

Answer (score 2):

[SMS2PC](http://www.androidcentral.com/android-quick-app-sms2pc) will let you see, reply and compose SMS messages on your desktop.  All the message are synced back to the phone too.  I tried it yesterday and it works great.  Wifi only, though.

Answer (score 1):

"BlueKeyboard JP" in the Android Market is an adequate free Bluetooth keyboard driver. [Here's my review and notes on special keys.](http://kpreid.livejournal.com/29817.html)

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the WiFi Keyboard, and it's magic, all you have to do is,

1. Connect you handset to a wifi network.
2. Install WiFi Keyboard on your handset.
3. On any text field, long press the field and choose Input Method; Wifi keyboard.
4. Instructions will pop, one screen of instruction.
5. Write the IP from your instructions screen on your handset on your PC's browser.
   That's it, and it gets better, if you are a gamer, like me, you have a gaming mode option on the screen of your PC, choose it, and arrows will work for gaming, try it with Doom for example.

Performance is biblical by the way.

Comment: I would assume that if you had a full-sized keyboard and is using WiFi keyboard, that means you had a full-sized computer in front of you as well; why not play the desktop Doom?

Answer (score 0):

Android Manager will let you do this as well.  It connects over WiFi to your phone to send and receive SMS messages and it also allows other stuff to sync over WiFi with your computer, for free.  I've found this to be a great program.

Answer (score -1):

[MyPhoneExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client)

I've been using it for my SE phone, and now for my android phone. Getting it to work via bluetooth was a little tricky until I read the faq at the developer's site.