# Standalone Chrome to phone outside browser?

Tags: google-chrome-to-phone

Is there any standalone version of chrometophone ? I use the firefox one.

I would like to be able to send text to the clipboard easily but with the browser extension I have to type into a form text box and then right click to send it to the mobile's clipboard. This is something I find I use very often but it's far from ideal especially for sensitive data.

Jumpnotes is another c2dmm application that does help, but it's still not ideal. I would love to see some desktop client that can do all the c2dm functionality with keyboard shortcuts.

One of the reasons I need this is that my gmail is filtered at work so if I want to reply to an email I have to scrape it out on the mobile itself or type up some text for the clipboard and paste it into a new email.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 3):

You need Evernote! http://www.evernote.com/  They have a web interface and an Android app.  It's really pretty fantastic!

Comment: Thanks for that one, I just heard about it today on lifehacker. Guess what, it's F)$(f9g blocked!! My god I hate websense, I hate websense so very very much.

Comment: There are Chrome and Firefox addons for Evernote.  They are probably blocked as well, but it maybe worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that [DropBox](http://dropbox.com) isn't blocked, then maybe a note-taking or todo type app that syncs with Dropbox could help? For instance [Epistle](https://market.android.com/search?q=epistle) or [Todo.txt Touch](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.todotxt.todotxttouch)

Alternately do you have Wifi at work that your phone can connect to? You could use the [Wifi keyboard](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.volosyukivan&feature=search_result) app that lets you type or paste from the PC straight into whatever text box is currently active on the phone. There are also apps that do the same over Bluetooth if that's a better option (though I haven't personally used them). See [this previous answer for some similar connectivity options](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4546/can-i-connect-an-android-phone-to-an-external-monitor-keyboard-and-mouse/4556#4556).

Comment: JumpNotes is similar to this, but not based on dropbox. It is c2dm based so it stays in sync pretty well. They also block external wifi! They are very paranoid. Just to make things better, I can only get a crappy GPRS connection despite being in central london! Love your tips though thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Clipbird](http://www.clipbird.net/). It can sync clipboards between your PC and your phone. You don't really need to do anything special, it will just sync them up.