# Android with mouse, keyboard and touchpad

Tags: keyboard, hardware

What should I do to be able to use my USB keyboard and mouse with my Android 2.1 tablet?

I like the idea of bluetooth, but my tablet doesn't support bluetooth.

Is there some device similar to touchpad that can be used instead of tapping to screen?

thank you for answer

Comment: Which tablet you own?

Comment: @Nathan Campos Archos 7

Comment: See also http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4546/can-i-connect-an-android-phone-to-an-external-monitor-keyboard-and-mouse though most of the answers there involve either bluetooth or a manufacturer supplying a "docking station" for that specific make/model.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use a keyboard and/or mouse with android. This is not supported unless you have android 3.1 or later. That is the first version that supports [USB Host Mode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/host.html).

For "normal" USB devices, if your device does not support them, you will probably need a [MicroUSB -> USB adapter](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&nord=1&q=microusb%20to%20usb%20adapter&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1920&bih=1139&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=17325066659740782202&sa=X&ei=0gz2TYqqMJLAgQe5h6HvCw&ved=0CKQBEPMCMAQ), or a [MiniUSB -> USB adapter](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&nord=1&q=miniusb%20to%20usb%20adapter&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&biw=1920&bih=1139&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=16626820935019249560&sa=X&ei=QA32Td-xFMjYgQeB59DYCw&ved=0CKMBEPMCMAI).

Comment: @Rayn Conrad : Thank you. And if I have android 3.1 do I need some reduction for USB cable from keyboard and mouse? Or have I to buy keyboard and mouse with special USB endings?