# How to connect both a monitor and a keyboard to a LG G3?

Tags: charging, usb-on-the-go, external-keyboard, external-display, slimport

Using USB-on-the-go I can connect a keyboard to an LG G3 and using a slimport adapter I should be able to connect a monitor. Is there a way to connect both at the same time? Or even better, connect both *and* be capable of charging them somehow.

Comment: If answers turn out to apply to all slimport supported phones I will generalize to that after those answers are given. If not I will keep it LG G3 specific.

Comment: [Related](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2437305) he is able to charge and connect a hard disk at the same time. In your case you can connect a keyboard and monitor. You need to use an usb single to double usb extender.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I connect an Android phone to an external monitor, keyboard and mouse?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4546/can-i-connect-an-android-phone-to-an-external-monitor-keyboard-and-mouse)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use your slimport to charge and HDMI and get a bluetooth keyboard and mouse, that is the optimal configuration. The only dumb thing LG didn't predicted is to turn off the phone display when you are using an external.