# How do I connect my Android Device to an external touchscreen?

Tags: applications, touchscreen, external-display

I would like to know if there is any chance to connect my device to an external, touch sensitive display, such as ordinary touchscreen monitors. If yes, then how do I do that?

There are many solutions out there or coming up that would might be an option but I could not find anything related being close enough to my question.

Those solutions are:

1. Matchstick
2. PiCast
3. AllCast
4. Raspberry Pi

I found similar reads:

1. [How can I connect an Xperia X8 to an external monitor?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4546/can-i-connect-an-android-phone-to-an-external-monitor-keyboard-and-mouse)
2. [USB touchscreen on Android 4.0.3 -> not possible to select (only moving the pointer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896471/usb-touchscreen-on-android-4-0-3-not-possible-to-select-only-moving-the-poin)
3. [Connecting Android tablet to external Touch screen](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?s=ec87f5223606d22ffc2c19fb25dcc13e&t=1294268&page=2)

But the final end user friendly step is still missing.

It would be nice to have a kind of reversed [iDisplay](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idisplay.virtualscreen), simple and user friendly. I just don't want to buy anything additional just for the bigger screen when my smartphone has already all the necessary hardware.