# Using your smartphone as Laptop and Desktop with a DisplayLink-Setup (with S7 for example)

Tags: samsung, usb, usb-on-the-go, external-keyboard, external-display

I want to buy an Samsung S7, but I also want to use it as a laptop and desktop replacement. What I have in mind is a workflow like [seen in this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFulMBNvjZA). After some researching how this could be done with the S7 I found out that it hasn't MHL (which might be problematic), and that what is done in the video might not work. Luckily I came across the [DisplayLink technology](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/android).

So I want to buy a [compatible docking station](http://www.displaylink.com/products/universal-docking-stations), for example [this one](http://www.accellcables.com/products/usb-3-0-full-function-docking-station). And as I read with USB OTG the phone could not charged I would use a [wireless charger](http://www.samsung.com/de/mobile-accessories/wireless-charger-ng930-galaxy-s7-s7-edge/EP-NG930BBEGWW/). Then some mouse and keyboard (bluetooth or usb with the docking station) and I would be happy. Also I would buy me a [portable display](https://www.wiknix.com/best-portable-monitor-for-laptop/) and a power bank.

But before I go and buy it, has anybody experience with such a setup? I find it rather difficult to find information on these setups. I found [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4546/can-i-connect-an-android-phone-to-an-external-monitor-keyboard-and-mouse) here, but it is from 2011 and so not very up to date. So will this setup work? What solutions have you guys for such a setup?

If it might not work, or might be problematic, please feel free to offer alternative solutions, also suggesting different phones, as despite the S7 is my favorite up to now I am still open for other options that do what I want them to do.

EDIT: At the end of [this post](http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s7-edge/648138-s7-s7-edge-mhl-hdmi-support-2.html) a user confirms that the Lenovo's DisplayLink (AN9017A1) works with the S7.

Answer (score 3):

Not having MHL is not problematic.

Most recent Android phone will be able to act as host and therefore talk with a docking station with DisplayLink technology inside. 
You simply need the app and an OTG cable. You are correct that the USB standard, until Type-C, only allows a device to be charged, not the host. However, some phones do charge whilst being host. They are not compliant, but in this case it may help you! It means you can find non-compliant cables to do that, which may not work with your phone model.
Android stock only allows you to have 1 external display in mirror/clone. The mouse is handled on one display properly. Android stock does **not** allow you to have an extended desktop because the launchers need to be modified to ask where to launch the app, and the mouse pointer also needs to be handled. DisplayLink, my current employer, has shown it is possible by modifying the launcher/OS. It just needs a manufacturer to embed that in their image...

Here are my recommendations on this. If you use it at a desk and not mobile, I would use a USB travel adapter plugged in to a standard monitor. This will allow you to plug to any conference room/hotel TV to display videos, presentations, show photos to family on their TV... directly from your phone. 

If you wish to have a mobile office, the mobile monitors are very nice. They are also quite interesting for trade shows as light and not requiring a power adapter. Still, driving the display and the back-light needs juice! Your mobile phone may not be able to provide all that juice directly (and even if it does, you may not want it to :) ). Some of these monitors come with a USB Y-cable. You would plug one to the OTG, the other cable to power bank.

Personally, I use a USB-C to Type-A adapter and a miniRay projector from my Oneplus 3 phone.

I hope this helps you see a bit more clearly what's possible!

Thanks,
Alban

Comment: Thanks for the answer! First, it might be basic but what is a USB-Travel Adapter in this context? Something to charge a device by usb? I cannot see what usage you want to suggest here... Second, the miniRay sounds interesting, maybe can you be more specific on your setup (again what kind of travel adapter??)... and lastly, I opened a somehow related post here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169761/here-is-display-mirroring-by-usb-cable-with-the-s7-but-the-s7-does-not-supports Maybe you want to take a look :)

Answer (score 1):

use chromecast.

The setup would be:-

- A chromecast connected to a display by HDMI port
- the phone connected by bluetooth keyboard and mouse(Something like Logitech K480)
- the phone charged by usb.
- Phone's display mirrored on the chromecast

Comment: Thanks. But Chromecast requires a host wifi (or at least you need a third device to set up a hot spot). But that is not practical when I am traveling for example. I tried miracast, this works but is laggy. So I would prefer something less laggy (which might be cable-based necessarily..)

Comment: Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter. It sets up its own adhoc wifi and from what I have read, it has very less time lag. And as S7 and S7 edge don't have MHL, it is very diificult to have a wired connection. Some wired connections do exist but they work over adb but they are very laggy. You can find these cables on eBay.