# Here is display mirroring by usb cable with the S7, but the S7 does not supports MHL and DisplayLink is also not used. So how does this work?

Tags: samsung, usb, usb-on-the-go, external-display

In the Youtube-Video [Samsung Galaxy S7 Android 6.0 phone Mirror Link for Joying Android 5.1 lollipop 1024*600 car stereo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KeeHZ2a8hbo)  he shows how to connect his Samsung S7 just by a USB-cable with an external monitor (in this case in a car system).

But how is this possible, as I read the S7 does not supports MHL, and the other option is DisplayLink? But in the video this is not mentioned, he does not installs the DisplayLink app which requires this, instead some "USB MOB driver".

So how is this realised, and is this also possible with other displays?

Remark: This question is closely related to [this recent one from me](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169553/using-your-smartphone-as-laptop-and-desktop-with-a-displaylink-setup-with-s7-fo).

Answer (score 1):

There is no driver in this video. MOB stands for mobile. 
It is using screen mirroring through debugger. Both systems are full Android machines, it's not just a display. MHL is to connect just a display.

Comment: Thanks, but what kind of debugger? Could you please be a little bit more specific on that?