# Plug physical keyboard to Samsung Galaxy SII

Tags: keyboard, samsung-galaxy-s-2

> **Possible Duplicates:**
> [External hardware keyboards](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/102/external-hardware-keyboards)
>
> [Can I connect an Android phone to an external monitor, keyboard and mouse?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4546/can-i-connect-an-android-phone-to-an-external-monitor-keyboard-and-mouse)
>
> [Bluetooth keyboard with Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/525/bluetooth-keyboard-with-android)

Is there a way to plug a physical keyboard to my Samsung Galaxy SII? Ideally they would connect via Bluetooth.

I wonder if it is possible at all to do some advance text editing, something like programming on the phone, and I clearly feel that the virtual keyboard is a bit limited.

Answer (score 0):

There are free apps that enable Bluetooth connectivity of keyboards like BlueKeyboard JP, Bluetooth Keyboard Easyconnect. There is also a paid app Bluetooth (Null) Keyboard. Try one of these for connecting your keyboard with your phone.